# c++ Concepts ensure class has a template member function

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

For example I have a class like this

```cpp
class Foo{
   template<typename T>
   void Do(){}
};
```

and I need to write a concept to ensure T is something like Foo and has templated Do method but without **instantiating** this method.

I tried something like that

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept FooLike = requires(T t){
   t.template Do<int>();
};
```

It works in most cases.

But some realizations may have static_assert on typename T.

```cpp
class FooButNotForInt{
   template<typename T>
   void Do(){
      static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>, "INT not allowed"); 
   }
};
```

That is why I need to check without instantiation.

Comment: But the concept [doesn't trigger](https://godbolt.org/z/M11P3f563) the static assertion inside the function. So what exactly do you care about?

Comment: I think that it's not possible to detect a template which will static_assert if instantiated.

Comment: @康桓瑋 In my case it's [triggered](https://godbolt.org/z/qax11YGP1)

Comment: _"has templated Do method"_ - Why is it important that it's implemented as a function template?

Comment: _"ensure T is something like Foo"_ - Exactly `Foo`? Convertible to `Foo`? What does "something like" mean?

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>, "int is invalid");` looks like a mistake. If `int` is invalid, you should assert on that `T` is **not** `int`, and [then it works](https://godbolt.org/z/1393PvxjG)

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are right! I mistyped here and broke my head on making it works. I should read my compiler errors more carefully. 康桓瑋 is also right.

Comment: This works on this example but not in my real code. I'll update my question later.